# Working with variadic functions in own fscanf

Tags: c, variadic-functions

So the context here is that I'm working on an own implementation of vfscanf. I currently have the following two function signatures:

```c
int k_fscanf_l(uint32 HA, FILE *stream, int max_length, char *format_tok, int *bytes_moved, void *va_list_item)

int k_vfscanf(uint32 HA, FILE *stream, const char *format, va_list args)
```

k designates kernel, v designates variable length, and the l is just my flavor of string length-accounting variant.

`k_fscanf_l` is a helper function that handles a bunch of the heavy duty work for `k_vfscanf`. In terms of what each function does specifically:

`k_vfscanf` takes a format string and breaks it down into singular tokens and individually passes them down to `k_fscanf_l`, or in the case of characters to a separate `k_fread` function (don't... ask). Inside `k_fscanf_l` I call `sscanf(lstrPtr, mod_tok, va_list_item, &offset)` to do most of the heavy work for me, I handle the file stuff aside from that myself.

There's a lot more I could say to over-describe this but I believe it's simpler to get to the crux of the question, which has to do with the last argument in each function. My program is currently asserting from indexing into `va_list args`, so I wanted to ask:

Questions:

1. Is it strictly incorrect to index into `va_list args` like so: `(void *)args[va_list_index]` and pass that along to `k_fscanf_l`?
2. Should I be using the predefined macros instead of void pointers to achieve what I want?
3. Is it even possible to achieve what I want? That is, can I divvy up the `va_list args` as multiple `void *va_list_item` pointers to be filled by `sscanf` inside the helper function? Do I have to change the function signature?
4. Do I have specify the types if I call the `va_arg` macro or is there a (void *)-esque solution?
5. If not answered above, what would you recommend in this situation?

I currently do the tokenization of the format string and calls to the helper function in the same loop, but I could break those into 2 passes instead to know strictly how many iterations I will do before working with va_list, I just don't know if I can pass the individual items down to be filled even if I do that.

Edit 2: Updating the snippet to be more encompassing

```c
else if (tok_len > 1)
   {
      // Character(s) - Deterministic length and compatibility with byte characters
      if (ft_low == 'c')
      {
         int num_chars;
         ret_val = sscanf(formatTok, "%d", &num_chars);
         if (ret_val < 1)
            num_chars = 1;
         k_print_message(HA, NOTE, 0, "vfscanf", "\tGot %d characters for specifier\n", num_chars);
         
         ret_val = k_fread(HA, va_arg(args, void *), num_chars, 1, stream);
      }

      // %N case - Does not need to actually call scanning function
      else if (ft_low == 'n')
      {
         int *va_list_count = va_arg(args, int *);
         *va_list_count = byte_offset;
      }

      // Strings - Hard to predict strings and scansets, support max length available for buffer
      else if (ft_low == 's' || ft_low == ']')
         ret_val = k_fscanf_l(HA, stream, MAX_LSTR_IN, formatTok, &temp_offset, va_arg(args, char *));
      
      // Non-Floating Numbers - Common bases shouldn't reach 16 digits, ever
      else if (ft_low == 'i' || ft_low == 'd' || ft_low == 'u' || ft_low == 'o' || ft_low == 'x' || ft_low == 'p')
         ret_val = k_fscanf_l(HA, stream, 64, formatTok, &temp_offset, va_arg(args, int *));

      // Floating Point Numbers - resolutions should never reach 64 digits, ever
      else if (ft_low == 'f' || ft_low == 'e' || ft_low == 'g' || ft_low == 'a')            
         ret_val = k_fscanf_l(HA, stream, 64, formatTok, &temp_offset, va_arg(args, float *));

      // Updates value
      byte_offset += temp_offset;
      if (ret_val > 0)
         stored_items++;
      else if (ret_val < 0)
         break;
   }

   k_print_message(HA, NOTE, 0, "vfscanf", "\tGot ft_low: %c\n", ft_low);
   k_print_message(HA, NOTE, 0, "vfscanf", "\tGot ret_val: %d\n", ret_val);

   // Resets flag
   null_flag = 0;

   // Deallocates memory
   kernel_free(HA, formatTok);
}

// Closes va_list from iteration
va_end(args);
```

Comment: `va_list args` is not certainly a pointer to indexable items.

Comment: To me it looks like #4 is the crux of the matter.  The answer there is yes.  For #5, [Formatted print without the need to specify type matching specifiers](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/115143/29485) may offer insight to alternatives.

Comment: So as I understand it your suggestion is to use the `va_list` macros to iterate through it. I believe it might be a bit easier for me to just break apart my cases to be less clustered, rather than implement Generics.

That said, it still leaves unanswered the question of whether I can pass along pieces of `va_list` "by reference" to the helper function. 

Would I simply call the helper like so (assuming integer type): 

`va_arg(va_list_item, *int);` 

and then

`k_fscanf_l(HA, stream, 16, formatTok, &temp_offset, va_list_item);`

Comment: `va_list` is some complete type.  Might be a `struct`, array, integer, etc.  C does not define much to do with `va_list` other than a few macros and function calls.  I see no _portable_ way to sub-divide `va_list`.  In fact, it is a good example of [information hiding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_hiding).  User code is not supposed to mess with it except in a few prescribed ways.

Comment: I see, so the most I can do is assume its contents and size based on the function it's in? Like pointers in scanf?

Comment: You could do `sizeof (va_list)`, but I do not see that benefitting in any way.  Its contents are implementation defined.  Akin to `FILE`.  Who knows what that is?  All I/O functions just get/use a `FILE *`.  IMO, treat `va_list` like a black-box.  You know it is there, but not what is inside, nor how to use other than a few helper macros, functions.

Comment: You say ```// Non-Floating Numbers - Common bases shouldn't reach 16 digits, ever``` — that seems an odd assertion.  Base-2 (Binary) integers require 32 bits for a 32-bit type (e.g. `int32_t`) and 64 bits for a 64-bit type (e.g. `long long` or `int64_t`).  A maximal 64-bit integer requires 19 decimal digits, possibly with a sign.  I think you're under-estimating the lengths necessary.

Comment: I suppose it's presumptuous to assume they won't go ham on the binary and I'll touch that up, thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 2):

> 1. Is it strictly incorrect to index into `va_list args` like so: `(void *)args[va_list_index]` and pass that along to `k_fscanf_l`?

It is strictly outside the bounds of the semantics defined by the C language specification to do so.  As far as C itself is concerned, therefore, the behavior of doing that is undefined.  If your C implementation happens to document semantics for such usage, and if you are not concerned with portability to other C implementations, then that might not be a concern for you.  Otherwise, that approach is at best unwise.

> 2. Should I be using the predefined macros instead of void pointers to achieve what I want?

The `va_start`, `va_arg`, `va_end`, and `va_copy` macros are the only means documented by the C language specification for working with `va_list`s.  If your implementation documents additional features for the purpose then it's reasonable to consider using them (thereby incurring a portability cost).  If not, then it is unwise to attempt to use anything other than the macros.

> 3. Is it even possible to achieve what I want? That is, can I divvy up the `va_list args` as multiple `void *va_list_item` pointers to be
>    filled by `sscanf` inside the helper function? Do I have to change the
>    function signature?

Independent of the specifics of variadic argument handling, you cannot perform such a split if your function is to support POSIX-style `%n$` input directives, as these disconnect the order in which directives appear from the order in which the corresponding pointers appear.  But that may not be a concern for you.

I also think that trying to use `sscanf` in support of scanning data from files presents some significant challenges entirely separate from argument interpretation.  But I'll suppose you have that part sorted.

As far as obtaining destination pointers from the `va_list`, you do have the advantage that for valid calls to this specific function, all the variable arguments must be object pointers.  If you can rely on all pointer-to-object types to have the same representation, then you can probably get away with extracting the variadic arguments via a series of evaluations such as ...

```
    void *va_list_item = va_arg(args, void *);
```

That might be sufficient for your purpose.  **HOWEVER**, C explicitly does not define the behavior of that approach when the actual argument is neither a pointer to `void` nor a pointer to a character type, and that is at best an uncomfortable situation to put yourself in.

If you want to conform strictly to C then you have to parse the format string at least enough to determine the correct (pointer) type of each argument, and use that type to extract the argument from the `va_list`.  Having done so, you can safely convert the result to type `void *` to pass on to your helper function, and such conversions are even automatic.

> 4. Do I have specify the types if I call the `va_arg` macro or is there a (void *)-esque solution?

See above.

> 5. If not answered above, what would you recommend in this situation?

I am a fan of strict conformance, so in general, I would recommend extracting the variable arguments using their correct types.  This presents the least likelihood of unpleasant surprises, though it does mean that you would have to duplicate some of the work that `sscanf` already has to do.

On the other hand, if there were some kind of general development policy for the project that it's ok to break strict aliasing by treating object pointer types as interchangeable (not merely interconvertible), then there is little additional harm done by relying on that policy by pretending that the variable arguments are all of type `void *`.

Comment: Thanks for the the thorough answer. It feels like my understanding of va_list macros is worse than I feared, I'm utterly failing to understand what's going wrong or why, anymore. I've tried implementing various interpretations of the information you gave me, the latest failure in the new Edit, and I'm at a bit of a loss.

Comment: @Kosba2, I'm sorry you're having trouble, but it's not clear what kind or how it manifests.  I do note, however, that if you want to read the variable arguments as their specific (expected) types, then you need to take any length modifier characters into account (`l`, `h`, `hh`, *etc*).